# SSRS: Expression to filter by datepart

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset which contains phone data for a given period, i need to filter this data based on the hour of the day so i can use this in a chart which shows the peak periods.

So far, i have this expression:

```
=Count(IIF(DatePart("h", Fields!CallStart.Value = 7), Fields!ID.Value, 0))
```

So, what i had hoped this expression would do is replicate this SQL Query:

```
select * from PhoneData
where MONTH(callstart) = 7 and YEAR(callstart) = 2012 and DATEPART(HH, callstart) = 7
and Direction ='i' and Part1Device not like 'v%' and Continuation = '0'
```

The month and year are set in the dataset query.

Suffice to say, the expression doesn't work and i can't quite figure out why.. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your closing bracket for the DatePart function is in the wrong place. Try this.

```
=Sum(IIF(DatePart("h", Fields!CallStart.Value) = 7, 1, 0))
```

Comment: I had tried this previously, it doesn't work unfortunately. I should only get 13 rows back but i get over 6000.

Comment: @DeanMcGarrigle Are you comparing it to the whole SQL query you are trying to replicate? You can only compare it to **select * from PhoneData where MONTH(callstart) = 7**. You still have more where conditions to write in the reporting services expression.

Comment: No not the whole query. The query above is what i am using for the data-set, using parameters for the year and month, so the data is already filtered. Its just the hour i need, hence the expression.

Comment: @DeanMcGarrigle I have amended my answer. Replaced Fields!ID.Value with 1 and changed to Count to Sum.